# Перенос ssh ключа на другую машину

Tags: linux, ssh

Сгенерил ключ на рабочей тачке, понадобилось этим ключ конектится с домашней. Принес домой ключ. скопировал в .ssh каталог.

**Сделал:**

```
ssh-add .ssh/background
```

Проверяю конект пишет:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/background
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

т.е. ломится к стандартным id_rsa, а мой не хочет проверять. Что делаю не так?

Comment: Это у вас опечатка? – `ssh-add .sss/background` – на самом деле `.ssh/...` ведь? Вы оба ключа скопировали ведь и pub и private? Permission'ы у файлов ключа правильные?

Comment: точно, поправлю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/background
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
```

была предложена для аутентификации публичная часть секретного ключа, хранящегося в файле `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/background`.

удалённый *sshd* её отверг. возможную причину можно узнать на этой машине в логе, куда поступает информация от *sshd*. в *debian-основных* дистрибутивах это обычно `/var/log/auth.log`.

возможные часто встречающиеся причины:

- подключаетесь не к тому пользователю, к которому требуется
- у этого пользователя не прописана публичная часть используемого ключа в `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (`~/.ssh/authorized_keys2`)
- у этого пользователя не заблокирован доступ всем, кроме него, к каталогу `~/.ssh` и к его содержимому:

  ```
  $ chmod -R go= ~/.ssh
  ```
- у этого пользователя каталог `~/.ssh` (или его содержимое) принадлежит другому пользователю (например, *root-у*):

  ```
  $ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.ssh
  ```

Comment: есть вероятность, что админ не добавил еще мой на тот сервер.

Comment: это вторая из перечисленных мною часто встречающихся причин.

Comment: А руками переносить ключ на другую машину вообще безопасно?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, какую часть ключа и в каком плане?

Comment: Приватную часть. ТС пишет, что "Принес домой ключ. скопировал в .ssh каталог.". Чтобы заработало, явно ему нужно принести так обе части.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, наверно, не очень безопасно. на улице ведь можно и, например, под машину попасть. или я чего-то не понял.

Comment: Иронизируете? ) Я скорее о том, что можно скомпрометировать ключ. И мне кажется более правильным иметь уникальный ключ на каждой машине и просто добавлять все публичные в `authorized_keys`. Но я не эксперт по безопасности, поэтому уточняю.

Comment: Как скомпрометировать: можно банально забыть удалить его с флешки, потом флешку дать кому-то попользоваться. Если ключ почтой отправлен, то ещё меньше уверенности.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я тем более не эксперт. но, вероятно, именно ношение приватного ключа с собой выглядит более безопасно, нежели копирование его на машины, которые остаются на некоторое время без присмотра. // от угроз же безопасности, связанных с потерей носителя, страхует, вероятно, шифрование: самого ключа, файловой системы.

Answer (score 1):

Публичный ключ RSA в authorized_keys не пробовали добавлять?

```
cat background.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Это на сервере нужно сделать?

Comment: Делаешь на той машине, к которой подключаешься